# Wordpress - send post to admin email when posting?

Tags: email, wordpress

I have a niche website that needs to allow users to post events and other things to the website.  Wordpress works perfectly for this option (as well as other needs).  The problem is, there is also a weekly newsletter (published as a PDF file) that gets sent to a large opt-in email list.  Is there any way to configure Wordpress (via plugin or hack) to send the CONTENTS of the post to the admin in a csv or rtf file of some sort?  The posts themselves will have several custom fields.  Most of the stuff I churn up when I search for "post to email" for Wordpress is the other way around, for people wanting to send an email and have that post to their site, which is not what I want to do.  I suppose other ideas of getting around my problem are open to consideration too.  Thanks!!

Comment: By 'contents of the post' do you mean the contents of the uploaded pdf file?

Comment: No, sorry for the clarity.  The pdf file is the "end result" here.  But we also need the same contents posted to the web.  And it needs to be done by someone with basic Wordpress/website knowledge, so no going into phpMyAdmin and extracting any tables.  Just looking for something simple here, and maybe I'm over thinking it... Looking into RSS ideas now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I am thinking you could accomplish this but haven't tested it. You could make a php script to parse the rss feed and email that contents. Depending on whether how many posts get done in a week, you could either create a function for it to fire after the post is posted; or have a cron job on it and send it once a week before the newsletter is to be sent. Sorry I'm not in front of my machine that has WP installed to test it out.